# 502 Exception - Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, virtual-machine

I have azure virtual machine, hosted angular application which is having NodeJs as a backend.

Sometimes it is throwing 502 exception.

[image: 502 Exception]

If we refresh the page and try to hit the api then we get response. But, sometimes it throws 502 and tells nothing other than this. We tried capturing IIS logs, there also no info about this exception.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is Server Side Problem. Kindly check the proxy or ip you're hitting. 502 Bad Gateway Error, which indicates that a server somewhere within the server stack — specifically, one which is acting as a gateway or proxy itself — received an invalid response from a different server.

Comment: If we try to hit the api after refresh, it is working. Can you please tell me what I need to check in the server side? We have VM, hosted angular site in the IIS & NodeJs in the IIS Node.